# Inversion in space

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, analysis

I'd like to show that if you consider the stereographic projection of the Riemann Sphere ($N$ is the pole) then circles on the sphere are conserved (except when they cross $N$)

I already showed that it is an inversion but how to show that an inversion in space conserve lines and circles? It's simplier with inversions in dimension 2.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you done so far? Thoughts?

Comment: It depends a little on how you define "circles on the sphere", but it shouldn't be hard to show that they are the intersections of (certain) planes in $\Bbb{R}^3$ with the Riemann Sphere (embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$, of course). As you know, inverting planes in $\Bbb{R}^3$ will give you planes or spheres, which will intersect with $\Bbb{C}$ (embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$) as lines or circles. This was how I did it in my PhD thesis.

Comment: I proved that if $P'$ is the image of $P$ by the projection we have $\overrightarrow{NP}.\overrightarrow{NP'} = 4$. Now I choose an inversion f with pole O(0,0,0) with radius $1$. This can be expressed as $f(X) = \frac{X}{||X||^2}$. In these conditions it is difficult to show that $f$ transforms circles in circles etc.